# Ошибка при запуске Web службы C#

Tags: c#

При запуске веб-сервиса на локальной, возникает ошибка

> Сообщение об ошибке синтаксического анализатора: Не удается найти тип поставщика CodeDom "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Удалить надо  из пакетов Nuget Roslyn компилятор:

> PM> Uninstall-package
> Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
>
> PM> Uninstall-package Microsoft.Net.Compilers

Если тоже самое продолжается, удалить из Web.Config